# Play Framework: How to separate mixed http/https endpoints for REST webservice?

Tags: web-services, apache, rest, https, playframework-2.0

I have a question regarding implementing SSL security using Play Framework.

First, I don't have much experience with Play, this is my first attempt at it, so any help would be appreciated.

I've developed some webservices using Play Framework (Java version 2.2.0), and I've tested them out both using http, as well as Play's built-in https feature.

The services are meant to be used by an external mobile app, and should allow for basic user authentication. What I'd like to accomplish would be to offer some endpoints (namely, user login) through https, while keeping the other data-intensive endpoints available using plain http, for performance reasons.

What would be the best way to go about this? We'll probably use Apache as our HTTP/HTTPS server, but I'm not familiar with it and haven't found any info about this in my research.

Edit: Right after I asked I found this reference from Apache website: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_faq.html#parallel ; so in fact it's possible to run two versions of the same server on http and https. My question now would just be how can I configure Play/Apache to make sure the endpoints I need can only be used by https, and the others using http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is popular approach which bases on forwarding the header from proxy to the Play application - `X-Forwarded-Proto` for an example, which lets you to determine the protocol, two first hits from search:

- https://serverfault.com/a/257643/118032 - forwarding the header with Apache
- http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/ (beware! this is Play 1.x article! not applicable for Play 2.x *out-of-the-box*, however it gives general concept overview)

You just need to declare custom method in ie. Application controller, for checking if the header exists and has value `https` (Java would be):

```java
public static boolean isSecureRequest(play.mvc.Http.Request request){
    return (request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null && "https".equals(request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto")));
}
```

so you can check it in every action with:

```java
public static Result index() {
    return (Application.isSecureRequest(request()))
        ? ok("This is secured request")
        : badRequest("INSECURE request!!!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.I'm using separate custom classes for authentication for services on http and https, extending from Security.Authenticator (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/java/play/mvc/Security.Authenticator.html), so it should be fairly simple to add that check to them, and then I won't need to change anything in the controller methods, just make sure the correct @Security.Authenticated(<className>.class) annotations are there for each method (added explanation just in case it helps someone else).